# Error while running Fastlane gym on a self-hosted Github runner

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, github-actions, fastlane

We've recently started getting this error while archiving the iOS app using Fastlane. Its been a while since we've upgraded to XCode 14 and not sure why this has started happening all of a sudden.

This is the command that fastlane gym runs:

> set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -scheme UAT -project projectname.xcodeproj -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' -archivePath /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2023-05-30/projectname\ 2023-05-30\ 12.06.52.xcarchive clean archive | tee /Users/username/Library/Logs/gym/projectname-UAT.log | xcpretty

The issue doesn't occur when ran locally on my machine but happens constantly when run remotely/locally on the runners.

My machine is an M1 Macbook pro and runners are Mac mini Intel Core i7.

> ```
>   MacOS: 13.2.1 Ventura
>   XCode: 14.3
>   Fastlane: 2.212.2
> ```

Things we've tried:

- Cleared derived data
- Reset SPM caches(`rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/org.swift.swiftpm & rm -rf ~/Library/org.swift.swiftpm`)
- Upgraded/Downgraded XCode version.
- Tried using different macs/runners.

> xcodebuild[655:6111] [MT] IDEFileReferenceDebug: [Load] <IDESwiftPackageCore.IDESwiftPackageSpecialFolderFileReference, 0x60000b241500: name:Docs.docc path:group:Docs.docc> Failed to load container at path: /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectname-ccmfvrcsvfhhqretcmokecenjwfq/SourcePackages/checkouts/swift-protobuf/Sources/protoc-gen-swift/Docs.docc, Error: Error Domain=com.apple.dt.IDEContainerErrorDomain Code=6 "Cannot open "Docs.docc" as a "Swift Package Folder" because it is already open as a "Folder"." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot open "Docs.docc" as a "Swift Package Folder" because it is already open as a "Folder".}